# Tried to fetch comments after question was removed by author resulted in error

Tags: bug, comments, closed-questions

The system currently does not handle this situation very gracefully.

If a user,

- Clicks on a question,
- Between clicking on the question and reading all visible comments the author removes the post,
- The user then tries to fetch more comments,
- This results in an error "Error fetching comments"

The user then has no idea why it failed until they try to refresh the page. If a question has been removed and someone tries to do *any* action on that page it should redirect them to the question removed by author page.

Comment: they shouldn't reject you, you should get an error saying the question has been removed IMO (the same message you get when answering a closed question).

Comment: @WouterJ well I don't want them *rejected* that would hurt peoples feelings, I just want them *redirected* so it's very obvious that the page doesn't exist any more.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I meaned redirected.

Comment: I don't know that I like the idea of a redirect for what's normally an AJAX load - worst-case, I could end up losing the draft of an answer I'm working on.

Comment: @Shog9 I think the idea behind doing a redirect would be that you would only do it upon a user action. So I don't see how you would lose a draft of an answer your working on. The most likely scenario would be you lose an answer you had just finished actually. And that stinks a little, but it wouldn't be a loss to the website, since the question is already removed by the author. Meaning you now have an answer without a question...

Comment: @Shog9 Well, no matter what happens, redirect or something else, something about the above flow needs to change...

Comment: @ryan: I can argue that this is too much of an edge case to actually be considered a problem. I mean, the first thing that I'd think to do in a situation like that would be to refresh.